# Logical operators inside of matrix notation in R

Tags: r, matrix, logical-operators

I have a dataframe of 5 variables. Each time one of them (tree, variable 3) changes, I need to pull the entire row and place it into a new object. The problem is I don't know of any logical operators for when a value changes from one row to the next. So I fully expected an error, and got that error. Here's the code I came up with to do this:

```
dat1<-read.csv("filepath", header=T) #Reads in file

dat<-NULL #Creates null object for for loop below

dat1<-as.matrix(dat1) #Code below only "works" on matrices

for (i in 2:198025) { if(dat1[i,3]-dat1[i-1,3]!=0){dat[i,]=dat1[i,]} } #Supposed to compare the row, i with the value of the row above.
```

I tried to do a subtraction because if the difference between rows is anything but 0, then that means the value must have changed. Problem is that R doesn't like logical expressions inside of matrix notation. I can't think of any other way to do this other than some lengthy linear combinations to find unique values and I know there must be a better way.

Here's some sample data

```
r1<- c(1,2,1,4,5)
r2<- c(1,3,1,5,6)
r3<- c(1,4,2,5,6)
r4<- c(1,4,2,6,7)
dat1<- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4)
```

It's not actual data, but you can use it to test the for loop. Basically, what I need is something that knows that since the 3rd variable changes between r2 and r3, that it should paste out r3 (the third row in dat1) into a new object.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, and it avoids using an explicit loop:

```
> ifelse(rbind(-1, apply(dat1, 2, diff)) == 0, dat1, NA)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
r2    1   NA    1   NA   NA
r3    1   NA   NA    5    6
r4    1    4    2   NA   NA
```

Comment: That doesn't paste out what I need though. It replaces the values with NA. I need to pull the entire row and save it. Basically, every time "tree" changes, I need to know what the values are for the entire row. So I would need to know what is in r3, and I'd really only have some of that data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to compare adjacent elements of a vector to check if they are the same and then keep the rows of a data.frame where the elements of that vector that do not match immediately previous elements:

```
# Let's say the third variable is the one of interest
myVec <- dat1[, 3]
# Now, create two vectors that have one element removed
myVecNoFirst <- myVec[-1]
myVecNoLast <- myVec[-length(myVec)]

# now check for changes, add one to the index to get the proper row
keepers <- which(myVecNoFirst != myVecNoLast) + 1
# keep the rows where a change occurred
datKeepers <- dat1[keepers,]
```